# Why are my <br> tags showing in my browser display for angular project

Tags: html, angular, frontend, line-breaks, display

I have text that is being saved from a textarea.  I save it to the database.  I now want to display this text onto another page after submit.  I would like to keep the same format as the original text input.

This is what shows up on the browser after redirecting to the other page.
Im replacing br with --- or else it will create actual breaks in this text.
--- equals br

"M <---><---/> O <---/><---/>C<---/>Hub<---/>"

How do I display onto the page without the br tags?  I have seen this work in other circumstances but unsure what I am doing wrong.

I have been able to use the .replace method to replace the enter's with 
.  The only thing though, the 
 tag is showing up in the display.

x.component.ts

```
  getMessages() {
    this._messageBoardService.getMessages().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.msgList = data
        this.msgList[0].message = this.msgList[0].message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
      })

  }
```

x.component.html

```
<h3>{{ msgList[0].title }}</h3>
<p> {{ msgList[0].message }}</p>
```

The expected output without the breakpoints is

M

O

C
Hub

Comment: are you replacing <br> just for display ?? I seems that your API is returning \n

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Yes it is for display purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is how angular works. It prevents from injection "bad html".
To print html you will need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Change your code

```
this.msgList[0].message = this.msgList[0].message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

to

```
 this.msgList[0].message =  sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.msgList[0].message.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"))
```

then template

```
<p [innerHTML]="msgList[0].message"></p>
```

**BUT** for security reason I would not do it I'd better do it with css

```
p.break-newline{
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

add class

```
<p class="break-newline"> {{ msgList[0].message }}</p>
```

And now you dont need to modify your message in code.

Comment: Thank you.  That was a good detailed answer and I didn't know about the DomSanatizer.  Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

If it is just for display purposes add a css property that displays your line breaks

```html
<p class="message">{{ msgList[0].message }}</p>
```

```css
.message { white-space: pre-line; }
```

in which case your api fetching has no operations

```js
getMessages() {
    this._messageBoardService.getMessages().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.msgList = data
      })
  }
```

---

**OR**

else you can do in angular is use innerHTML property

```
<p [innerHTML]="msgList[0].message"></p>
```